# Why does inheriting constructors break aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++

Why does inheriting constructors from a base class break aggregate initialization?

For example, this works:

```
struct MyArray : std::array<int, 2ul> {};

MyArray a{1, 2};
```

but this doesn't work:

```
struct MyArray : std::array<int, 2ul>
{
     using std::array<int, 2ul>::array;
};

MyArray a{1, 2};
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? The point of an aggregate is that it doesn't have any constructors (default/copy/move aside). Would you expect `MyArray a{1, 2};` then to be aggregate-initialization or to do overload resolution against the (inherited) constructors instead?

Comment: Wait a second... `std:: array` doesn't HAVE a constructor. Does `using std::array<int, 2ul>::array;` make any sense at all?

Comment: `std::array` has a [implicitly generated ctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) @user4581301

Comment: @user4581301 `std::array` has implicit default, copy and move constructors.

Comment: Good points, but it doesn't have a constructor that will eat an `initializer_list`, so it's not useless in the general case, but is useless here. I wonder if the rationale for the no inherited constructors rule is is an inherited constructor is or can't be easily distinguished from a user-defined constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17, aggregates can have base classes, so that for such structures being derived from other classes/structures list initialization is allowed:

```cpp
struct MoreData : Data {
    bool done;
};

MoreData y{{"test1", 6.778}, false};
```

In C++17 an aggregate is defined as

- either an array
- or a class type (class, struct, or union) with:

  - no user-declared or explicit constructor
  - no constructor inherited by a using declaration
  - no private or protected non-static data members
  - no virtual functions
  - no virtual, private, or protected base classes

For more details you can refer to *Chapter 4 Aggregate Extensions* from **C++17 - The Complete Guide** By Nicolai M. Josuttis

Comment: On second thought, this is how to get around the problem, not an explanation of WHY it's a problem.

Comment: I feel like this does answer my question, so thanks.  `no constructor inherited by a using declaration`

Comment: Dang, If I'd known, "Because them's the rules" was all you were looking for, I would have answered myself. Still not sure what got this answer a downvote, though.